# Show solution to each part of a multipart question right after that part in exam package

Tags: exam

I use the great `exam` package to write my exams as a teacher. It lets me typeset solutions too, but for multipart questions, I want the solution to each part printed right after that part. By default, `exam` writes the solution to the parts of a multipart question *together*.

Here's a minimum example:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
\printanswers

\begin{questions}
\question Below is the data for an ``E-core.''
\begin{parts}
    \part Describe what an E is.
    \part Describe what a core is.
\end{parts}

\begin{solution}
\begin{parts}
    \part E usually comes before F.
    \part Core is usually inside a crust.
\end{parts}
\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing what you have done thus far - this way it would easy to work from an existing platform.

Comment: @Werner, thanks for the hint. Off to edit. Thanks to superb StackExchange, my question is already answered!

Comment: Instead of posting a “Thank you”, you should thank @Gonzalo by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).

Comment: I accepted his answer. I will certainly upvote too once I have enough points. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example using the `solution` environment to print the solutions right after their corresponding part:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question
What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
  \part[5]
  Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
  \begin{solution}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{solution}
  \part[5]
  Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
  \begin{solution}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{solution}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]